# When running a build from Hudson, I'm getting: "Empty password used - try 'cvs login' with a real password"

Tags: hudson, cvs, cvsnt

Everything was working great with the build. Then this started popping up after the admins did some maintenace.

[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\CVSNT\cvs.exe" -q -z3 update -PdC -D "Monday, August 23, 2010 12:00:52 PM UTC"
Empty password used - try 'cvs login' with a real password

I've verified that CVS is working fine, and the account used to access CVS is working properly, and there were no code checkings that caused the issue.

Comment: This issue was fixed by just restarting the windows server itself. Not a great solution, but it got me off this and on to bigger problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was your CVS application updated that Hudson is using? Was Hudson updated? Find out what your administrators did before you do any further troubleshooting.